# Importing TensorFlow 1.9.0 on Jupyter Notebook Causes an Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow 1.12.0 using Anaconda Navigator, and when I try to import it on Jupyter notebook I keep getting this error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
```

I tried searching for a similar problem here, all I found was to install TensorFlow 1.9.0 instead of any other version. I tried that and it did not work. I even created a whole new environment on Anaconda Navigator and installed nothing but TensorFlow 1.9.0 on it and it still gave me the same error. I tried uninstalling the whole thing and starting over with 1.9.0 but it is no use. I tried all the older versions and they all still gave me the same error. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Here is the complete error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     57 
     58 # Protocol buffers
---> 59 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
     60 from tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2 import *
     61 from tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2 import *

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py in <module>
     13 
     14 
---> 15 from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
     16 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_function__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import versions_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_versions__pb2

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py in <module>
     13 
     14 
---> 15 from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
     16 
     17 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py in <module>
     13 
     14 
---> 15 from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
     16 from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import types_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_types__pb2

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py in <module>
     13 
     14 
---> 15 from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
     16 from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import types_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_types__pb2

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py in <module>
     20   syntax='proto3',
     21   serialized_options=_b('\n\030org.tensorflow.frameworkB\016ResourceHandleP\001Z=github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/framework\370\001\001'),
---> 22   serialized_pb=_b('\n/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"r\n\x13ResourceHandleProto\x12\x0e\n\x06\x64\x65vice\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\tcontainer\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\thash_code\x18\x04 \x01(\x04\x12\x17\n\x0fmaybe_type_name\x18\x05 \x01(\tBn\n\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\x0eResourceHandleP\x01Z=github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/framework\xf8\x01\x01\x62\x06proto3')
     23 )
     24 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
```

Comment: I finally managed to solve it. For anyone who might need it, I uninstalled protobuf and Tensorflow, then I reinstalled Tensorflow but with version 1.7.0. Apparently the version of protobuf I previously had was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue.
By updating the protobuf I got the error resolved.

Please try the below code for updating and check whether the problem is resolved:

**pip install -U protobuf**